# Not detecting onKeydown method when 'back' key is hit

Tags: android

From the onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu) method, I stopped the thread when I was about to display the menus because background thread, which consumes lots of processng time, makes displaying and clicking one of the menus(not the menu button) nearly impossible.  After the thread stops, displaying and clicking menus(not the menu button) becomes much more manageable. The problem occurred when 'back' key was pressed immediately after the menus were displayed. I need to restart the thread after when the user hits 'back' key, but there is no method(I tried onBackPressed() and onKeyDown()) that I know of intercept the 'back' key. I really appreciated if someone can answer this question.

Comment: Intercepting back on onKeyDown() I'm pretty sure never works, but onBackPressed() always works for me. Can you provide the code?

Comment: if you overide onbackPressed you can do whatever you want

Comment: Thanks very much for trying to help. I tried the onBackPressed() method, but it did not worked. Guess what? I partially fixed the problem: when I incorporated the public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)  method, the 'back' key pressed immediately after the menus were displayed did execute the void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)  method. However, when I displayed one of the submenus from one of the menus and then hit the 'back' key, the void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)  method did not get execute. You try it and get back to me. Thanks very much.

Comment: ghostbust555: Intercepting the back key using onKeyDown() always works.

Answer (score 0):

It always work for me

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // remover this line super.onBackPressed();
    Now you can do whatever you want, start your thread and any other task
}
```

**Edited According to new Question**

When back key will hit then android has it default action.So if you want to capture back key press then use onbackpressed and do what ever you want

Comment: I do not think that will work because the focus is not in Activity class(well, in my case, it is MapActivity) anymore when I pressed the menu button.

Comment: One thing i will make sure to you when you will press back button this code will 100 % call either in MapActivity or in simple Activity

Comment: I am sorry I could not post the code because the project is monstrous.

Comment: No. But thank goodness, with the onOptionsMenusClose() method I mentioned it above, partially solved. I updated a new question that is similar to this one.

Comment: Hello TofeeqAhmad, sorry I said it did not worked. But without understanding why, only once the onBackPressed() displayed while I was continuously testing the menu. However, the onOptionsMenusClose() method always executed from the main menu whenever I immediately hit the "back" key. The same issue, where the onOptionsMenuClose() did not executed when the submenus were displayed from clicking one of the main menues and then immediately hitting the "back" key, is still there.